# Docker build failing with invalid reference format

Tags: maven, docker, build

I am running into an issue while performing docker build. This works fine on my macbook. What could be happening?

Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1 (to create a "build" image, ~140MB)
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine3.7 AS builder
RUN java -version

COPY . /usr/src/transformer/
WORKDIR /usr/src/transformer/
RUN apk --no-cache add maven && mvn --version
RUN mvn package

# Stage 2 (to create a downsized "container executable", ~87MB)
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.7
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/transformer/target/transformer-0.0.*.jar .

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "./transformer-0.0.*.jar"]
```

Error on jenkins console:

```
Error parsing reference: "openjdk:8-jdk-alpine3.7 AS builder" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format


[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'properties'
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[transformer_Pull_Request] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins4154938563612856789.sh
+ exit 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
# Jenkins Build
Build #2: **Still Failing**  (Docker Build Failed)
Image :
## Services
****
```

Comment: What version of docker is running where this is failing? Quoting from the docs, "Multi-stage builds are a new feature requiring Docker 17.05 or higher on the daemon and client.".

Comment: You were exactly right. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Multi-stage" builds are a new feature requiring Docker 17.05 or higher on the daemon and client.

[Here is the link to the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

[@larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) helped with the answer. Thank you.